# C++ Inheritance: Variable with Type of a Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's imagine we have two classes.

```
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};
```

In another part of my code I want to have a variable of type `Base` which can also hold an object of type `Derived`.

```
Base b1, b2;
b1 = Base();
b2 = Derived();
```

In languages like Java or C# this is possible. In c ++, however, I get a slicing error.

Is there a way to replicate the behavior of for example Java in C++?

Comment: Are you familiar with value types vs reference types in those other languages? Are you familiar with the concept that all classes in C++ are essentially value types by default? Are you familiar with pointers and references? If no the any of these questions, then there's the research/learning you need to do.

Comment: you can replicate behavior, but the code will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In languages like Java and C#, object variables are *reference* types.  The *actual* objects are stored somewhere in dynamic memory, and the variables just *refer* to them, like pointers.

But in C++, objects can be created in automatic memory, static memory, dynamic memory, etc.  So when you have an object variable, that is the *actual* object, not a *reference* to the object.

There is no way to make C++ work the way you want for *value* types, only for *reference types*. So you MUST use a pointer/reference instead, otherwise [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) will occur, as you have already discovered.  Polymorphism requires the use of pointers/references in order to handle virtual dispatch correctly, etc.

```cpp
Base b;
Derived d;
Base &b1 = b;
Base &b2 = d;
```

```cpp
Base *b1 = new Base;
Base *b2 = new Derived;
...
delete b1;
delete b2;
```

Comment: So if I have a function ```foo()``` which can return values of type ```Base```and of type ```Derived```I have to return ```Base*```? Is this the proper way to do this in C++?

Comment: @Luke returning a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is the proper way to do it for a factory function (most of the time, it depends on where the responsibility for the destruction of the object lies).

Comment: @Luke yes, you would have to return a (smart) pointer in that case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pointers to accomplish that, ie this will work:

`Base* bs=new Derived();`

If you want to call a function that is defined in `Derived`, do the following:

`((Derived*)bs)->fn();`

Comment: `static_cast<Derived*>(bs)->fn();` would be preferred instead.  Making `fn()` virtual so the cast is not needed at all would be even better.